# How to change audio-speed with ffplay:

Tags: sound, lubuntu

if I have longer texts to read I like to have them read to me with the following script from https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Sprachausgabe/#SVOX-pico2wave .

```
1  #!/bin/bash    
2  pico2wave -l=de-DE -w=/tmp/test.wav "$(cat ${1})"
3  avplay -f wav -loglevel 0 >/dev/null -x 100 -y 50  -vn -autoexit /tmp/test.wav
4  rm /tmp/test.wav
```

Save the script as **svox.sh** in */usr/local/bin* and start it with

```
svox.sh TEXTFILE.txt
```

That works really well with English texts (with "*pico2wave -l=en-GB [...]*" in line 2 of course) but the audio-speed in German is a bit slow.

What I´ve tried so far is replacing line 3 with

```
avplay -f wav -loglevel 0 >/dev/null -x 100 -y 50  -vn -autoexit -filter:a "atempo=2.0" /tmp/test.wav
```

yet that didn´t work. In order to find out why that is I tried typing the following command in the terminal:

```
avplay -f wav -x 100 -y 50  -vn -autoexit -filter:a "atempo=2.0" test.wav
```

I got the following error-message:

```
[...]
Failed to set value 'atempo=2.0' for option 'filter:a': Option not found
```

So it seems that either the syntax isn´t correct or the option isn´t supported.
Does anyone know of a way to speed up the audio output?

P.S.:

my system: Linux/Lubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, 64 bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can use the `-af` option like so:

`ffplay -af "atempo=2" <audio_file>`

This will play the audio file at two times the speed. More info here:

https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html#Main-options

Comment: Thanks a lot, Robert. Your command works as desired nad is clearly of great help. Tnx again and have a Happy New Year.

Comment: Glad to be of help! Feel free to mark it as the answer. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1):

in the meantime I managed to solve this problem with a workaround. I use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

pico2wave -l=de-DE -w=/tmp/test.wav "$(cat ${1})"
ffmpeg -i /tmp/test.wav -filter:a "atempo=1.2" -vn /tmp/test2.wav  # increase speed by a factor of 1.2
firejail --net=none avplay -f wav -loglevel 0 >/dev/null -x 100 -y 50  -vn -autoexit /tmp/test2.wav  # play sound in a sandbox
rm /tmp/test.wav
rm /tmp/test2.wav
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to use MPlayer rather than FFplay there is a relatively easy method to accomplish your goal. Use the following syntax:

```
mplayer -af scaletempo -speed 0.5 my_file.mp4
```

Remember to replace `my_file.mp4` with the name of *your actual media file*. Now during playback you can use the following keys:

```
{   <---This key will dynamically slow the playback speed
}   <---This key will dynamically increase playback speed
```

Hopefully this will accomplish your goal.

**References:**

- [Top 10 Tricks and Tips for the svn MPlayer](http://www.andrews-corner.org/linux/topten.html) My own page with this particular MPlayer trick and a handful of others.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andrew. That´s exactly what I was looking for. I´m perfectly happy to use MPlayer and this command really does the trick. It´s really cool and I´m going to use in my script. Tnx also for your link. Seems like your homepage has a lot of interesting topics for me. Cheers.

Comment: @Rosika Great news :)